Render windows on inactive workspace in KDE Plasma Wayland
When I leave an application, usually a game, on inactive workspace it pauses seemingly because rendering is stopped.
I haven't found much information about it, only that it is caused by rendering being stopped for inactive workspaces.
I have read that gamescope with obs_vkcapture can help but they did not work for me.
I have attempted running applications with vk_xwayland_wait_ready variable but their rendering loop was still stopped.
How to unpause rendering on inactive workspaces?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

As a random workaround I can use 'Move to Desktop' -> 'Display on all Desktops' but it is hardly a solution. I imagine some really hacky solution could be done with kwinscript but surely there is a better way.

Same problem (Gnome 47 Wayland) - literally any game or app is "frozen" when on other desktop.
As solution - I was using https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1459/miniview/ - but it does not work on Gnome 47.
For example - https://playwithfurcifer.itch.io/backpack-battles (download and run in Wine, just as free game example) - click unranked - play(top middle) - observe how fast game play - then move game to other desktop - also press play - and move to other desktop - game freezes until you return back.
It is same in every multiplayer-game - and in P2P game where "you host" - everyone will be frozen until you as host return back.
As temporal bad solution - keep game on same "desktop" and just alttab.
Edit 1: gamescope - may be correct way to fix... but
gamescope -f -W 1920 -H 1080 -r 60 -- vkcube
gamescope -b -W 1920 -H 1080 -r 60 -- vkcube
(replace vkcube with your game like wine game.exe)
For me on Nvidia(565.77 driver, gamescope 3.15.14) - Native OpenGL games work but Vulkan/DXVK even if it start - frezes in few seconds.
So not working solution on Nvidia for now it seems.
Edit 2: export GAMESCOPE_ENABLE_WSI=0 and turning off all ingame vsynk or frame limit seems to solve freeze. maybe gamescope is solution if it work.

Gamescope doesn't work well for me, I am on nvidia too, there is a nvidia-specific gamescope fork but it too fails in some games. For now I am working with by setting the game window to display on all virtual desktops and minimizing it.

Same - gamescope work "1 of 3 times" and even if it launches/worked - there still some bugs.
For me as I said - having "full-screen game-window" as atl-tab (on same virtual desktop) - works, alt-tab is annoying but no other way for now.
